# Can't record audio with Macbook + Earbuds

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, microphone, ear-phones

I have a 2013 MacBook Pro Retina and I always used the EarBuds to talk on skype etc.. Suddenly it stopped working as the Audio Input. I still can listen to stuff, control the volume and everything else. The only problem is that It stopped capturing the microphone. I didn't change anything recently and this is how my sound settings are:

[image]

Can you give some tips on things to check? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

If you have not already, I would do a restart and as part of the restart clear the non-volatile RAM (NVRAM):

Hold down <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>all at the same time starting before the first system boot chimes and letting them chime 3 times before releasing.

Worked for me when that happened.

Comment: I just tried, it didn't work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: try a different set of headphones / microphone...

Comment: It was the first thing I tried. I thought my mic was broken, but it is not the case.